# Plot Magnitude[dB] vs. Frequency[deg] with matplotlib.pyplot python where Mag and Freq are two lists

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
# plotting Magnitud vs. Freq
figure1 = plt.Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
ax1 = figure1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(freq, mag_S11, color = 'r')
# ax1.set_ylim([-75, 50])
# ax1.set_xlim([0.0, 30.0])
scatter = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1, root) 
scatter.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH)
ax1.legend(['S11']) 
ax1.set_xlabel('Frequency [GHz]')
ax1.set_title('Magnitude[dB] Vs. Frequency')
```

My **freq** and **mag_S11** are 2 lists of more than 200 elements, the problem is I'm not getting the graph behavior I want. Am I plotting it correctly or the values are wrong?

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

That is because `plot` connects the dots. You want to either use `ax1.scatter(...)` with the current data or `ax1.plot(...)` with the data sorted so that x increases. Using

```
 freq, mag_S11 = sorted([freq, mag_S11], key=lambda x: x[0])
```

should sort both datasets by increasing frequency and let the plot work nicely.